# C++ simple encryption

Tags: c++, c, encryption

I am trying to do a simple encryption with a char and a key of the same length

```
#define u8 unsigned char
const int CHARMODMAX = 256;

u8 encrypt(u8 value, u8 key){
    int rawValue = static_cast<int>(value);
    int rawKey = static_cast<int>(key);
    return ((rawValue+rawKey)%CHARMODMAX);
}

u8 decrypt(u8 value, u8 key){
    int rawValue = static_cast<int>(value);
    int rawKey = static_cast<int>(key);
    int rawDiff = rawValue-rawKey;
    return rawDiff >= 0 ? (rawDiff) : (CHARMODMAX + rawDiff);

}
```

However it looks like I am losing precision after calling encrypt and decrypt. any help would be great, side note it's been a very long time since I have used C++ :)

Does the static cast to int loose precision? If so is there a better way to do this simple math

Comment: CHARMODMAX should be 256.

Comment: _"it looks like I am losing precision after calling encrypt and decrypt"_ Do you have any proof? Evidence? Data? We need a question that's more concrete than "any help would be great". How do you invoke these functions?

Comment: Don't the `%` and the `&` do the same thing? (Once you fix the error @immibis reported.)

Comment: I thought of the same thing because off the max value of unsigned char bing 256 (char string with terminating 0) but that did not solve the issue example: rawValue -> encrypt + decrypt -> endvalue
4800 -> 473f

Comment: so i have updated the code, correcting the CHARMODMAX and removing the & operation. However It still seems like i am missing something

Comment: Why don't you simply `return rawValue^rawKey` in both functions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short form for your functions:

```
u8 encrypt(u8 value, u8 key)
{
   return value + key;
}

u8 decrypt(u8 value, u8 key)
{
   return value - key
}
```

Promotion of `unsigned char` to `int` goes without loosing anything. The promotion back cause value truncation. so the operation:

```
(unsigned char)(x + y * 256)
```

Would always be equivalent to:

```
x & 255 // (or 0xFF)
```